# Abandon Audio Focus and continue previous music/video stream

Tags: java, android, audio, text-to-speech

I've implemented a TTS (Text to speech) feature in my application. Everything is working perfectly and now I've come across an issue in which I cannot find a solution to. 
Basically, I obtain the Audio Focus before activating my TTS function. In the real application, the music stops when I do that (which is exactly how I want it to behave). However, once the TTS function is finished, I abandon the audio focus and the music/video doesn't continue. I don't know how to continue the previous music/video stream which was playing before my TTS.

Here's the code I've implemented:

Code to abandon the audio focus once my TTS is finished:

```
@Override
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String s) {
    Log.v(TAG, s);
    if(!getUserPreference().getTest()){
        //setDefaultVolume();
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
    }
}
```

Code to obtain the audio focus before my TTS starts:

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

int requestAudioFocusResult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
if(requestAudioFocusResult == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED){...
```

I welcome any further questions regarding my question. Looking forward to the answers/suggestions. 
Changed according to the answer:

```
int requestAudioFocusResult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
```

I've implemented as the answer has stated but the requestAudioFocusResult value returns as 1 when it should be 3. Any idea?

Comment: _"value returns as 1 when it should be 3"_. The returned value [as stated in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#requestAudioFocus(android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,%20int,%20int)) is either `AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED` or `AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED`, i.e. 0 or 1.

Comment: @Michael I was comparing `requestAudioFocusResult` against `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK` when I should've been comparing it against `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN` to check if it's granted or not. That's why I was expecting the int to return as 3 instead of 1 but forgot the fact it was a boolean to determine true of false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> once the TTS function is finished, I abandon the audio focus and the music/video doesn't continue.

Since you're requesting audio focus indefinitely (`AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN`), the behavior you describe sounds like [the expected behavior](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html):

> [I]t’s assumed that another application is now being used to listen to audio and your app should effectively end itself. In practical terms, that means stopping playback, removing media button listeners—allowing the new audio player to exclusively handle those events—and abandoning your audio focus. At that point, **you would expect a user action (pressing play in your app) to be required before you resume playing audio**.

---

It seems to me like you ought to request temporary audio focus, i.e. `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT` (or `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK` depending on whether or not you think it's ok for other audio to keep playing in the background at a lower volume).

Comment: can you please check the question again as I've implemented the solution as you've stated.